# Pressure of water derived from weight vs pressure of water derived from Pascal's law

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-statics

Assume that I fill a floor measuring $ 2 m^2 $ in a room with $1 m $ of water, and the rest of the room is full of air.

I have used two ways of finding the pressure of the water on the floor:

First, the weight of the water can be expressed as $ M_{w}g = \rho_{w} V_{w} g \approx20000 N $

Using $ P = F / A  $ where the weight of the water is the force I'd get $ P = 20000 / 2 = 10000 N/m^2$

--

Doing it with Pascal's law, however, the pressure at the bottom of the water is:

$ P_{w} = P_{atm} + p_{w}gh = 1.03\cdot10^5 Pa + 1000 Kg/m^3\cdot10m/s^2\cdot1m \approx 113000 N/m^2 $

This being 10 times the result using the weight of water.

--

I'm pretty sure the second method is the right one but I wonder why the first one is not valid.

Comment: Why didn't you add the weight of the air in the first case?

Comment: But then should it be done calculating the column of air from the top of the atmosphere or just the room?

Comment: Top of the atmosphere. For every square inch, the weight is $14.7$ lb.

Comment: @mmesser314 AFAIK, as the density varies with altitude, the weight can't be the same every square inch

Comment: The weight over a square inch is the weight of the column of air from the floor to the top of the atmosphere, assuming the floor is at sea level. That weight is the same over each square inch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the second method is the right one but I wonder why the first one is not valid.

Both methods are right, but you are calculating different things with them. The first method you are ignoring the air so you are calculating the gauge pressure. If you include the air in the first method then it will match the second method. The second method you are including the air so you are calculating the absolute pressure. If you ignore the air in the second method then it will match the first method.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you just calculate the additional pressure of the water, wich is the only interesting thing, since th additional air pressure  was on the floor even without water. Usually you calculate the pressure from the water only. When you weight yourself  on a scales you also do not add the air pressure.